# Save bits in a stream of bytes in Android Java?

Tags: java, android, text, byte, bit

I need to save a binary stream, that I will later convert to text. Since binary streams don't exist in Java, I just saved my 'bits' in a stream of 'bytes' just to test my code. Now I have a stream of bytes where 1 bit is encoded on 1 byte.

```
byte [] stream = new byte [1500];
       int str = 0;
 byte [] data = new byte [1];
  for (int i = 0; i<original.cols(); i++)
                {
                    for (int j= 0; j<original.rows(); j++)
                    {
                       original.get(j,i, data);

                 if ((data[0]==0))
                        {
                            stream [str]=0;
                            str = str+1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            stream [str]=1;
                            str = str+1;
                        }
                    }

                }
```

Can anyone help me to properly save my bits encoded in a stream of bytes, where 1 byte would represent 8 bits ?

Comment: I don't know what `original` is. It is better to have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

A [`java.util.BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toByteArray--) contains helper methods for dealing with raw bits, and conversions to and from byte arrays. In the following example, `bytes` will contain a single byte:

```
int numberOfBits = 8;
BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(numberOfBits);
bitSet.set(3, true);
bitSet.set(7, true);

byte[] bytes = bitSet.toByteArray();
```